# Reuse variable in hook callback

Tags: functions, actions, child-theme

I'm setting up a child theme in WordPress and I can't make `add_action` to be fired within `functions.php`.

`Functions.php` is called and I can run code from within. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

```
$debug_msg = "Hi there!";

function test_function() {
    error_log($debug_msg, 0);

}
add_action('init', 'test_function', 20);
```

Comment: This code won't work, because you have your variable `$debug_msg` defined outside the function where it is called. Ohterwise it looks fine.

Comment: Oh, you may also want to use `wp_enqueue_scripts` as a hook for enqueueing styles rather than `init`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a variable from a another context in a function, create a class:

```
class CustomLog
{
    private $debug_msg = "";

    public function __construct( $msg )
    {
        $this->debug_msg = $msg;
    }

    public function log()
    {
        error_log( $this->debug_msg, 0 );
    }
}

add_action( 'init', [ new CustomLog( "Hi there!" ), 'log' ], 20 );
```

Now you can reuse the class multiple times for different messages and hooks.